# Restrict commerce coupon by user role

Tags: rules, commerce

I am making a drupal commerce site. For coupon functionality I am using commerce_coupon module .

My question is How can I restrict a coupon by user roles i.e. a particular coupon should be applicable only for authenticated users .

I have already installed Commerce Coupon - Per user redemption installed which gives me coupon per user functionality . But I want commerce coupon by user roles.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The coupon's applicability is tied to the discount. Use [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) and [Commerce Discount Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_extra). Commerce Discount Extra provides an inline condition that lets you specify a user/role condition for an order, which is exactly what you want.